# Difference between CD tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There are currently 239 questions tagged with [cd](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cd) and no distinction between *Compact Disc* and *Change Directory*. Additionally, there is no [chdir] tag. My thoughts are that there should be a **chdir** tag and all the non optical-media questions could be migrated to that tag.

Forgive me if this isn't meta-style and I should be doing this in the tags section, but I don't have enough rep.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There should be no [chdir](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/chdir) tag – keep in mind that we have the *nix `cd` command. Nobody would really use it, and it wouldn't make sense to use "chdir" for something that is well known as "cd". If I were to write a question about `cd`ing to a directory, which tag would I use, except for "cd"?

The other way round though, we can just use "compact disc" for the CD.

---

I suggest we look into the existing posts and see which use is more common (i.e. discs, or the command). Then, we retag those questions so that:

- The [cd](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cd) tag refers to the *nix command.
- The [compact-disc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/compact-disc) refers to the disc.

Create appropriate tag wiki excerpts so the distinction becomes clear. E.g. mention in the [cd](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cd) excerpt that compact discs have their own tag.

Comment: Mother. Is there a batch retagging tool?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The system only allows one tag to be exchanged with another, but not for a list of questions. This can only be done by the developers.

Comment: So superuser will need to look like a compact disc stack exchange for a while.

Comment: Someone help me?

Comment: @kinokijuf - you've gone about this the wrong way. We needed to work out how many questions would be affected by this and come up with the *least disruptive* way of sorting it out.

Comment: @kinokijuf Who told you that *you* should go ahead and do all of this on your own? We've been there before. I've stated my opinion here, and this is far from reaching consensus from the community.

Comment: Not that I disagree with this proposal, but if we go this way, should we have tags [tag:dvd] & [tag:blu-ray] as well as the new [tag:compact disc] point to [tag:media] or a new [tag:optical media]? It might be weird having the long version of CD and BRD but the short version of DVD as tags. Or it might not be weird. Just my 2 cents

Comment: @Raystafarian True that. I noticed it myself. The only problem is … we can't really undo that now. We could theoretically move the short tags from DVD etc. to the long form, and add synonyms from `[dvd]` > `[digital-versatile-disc]`, and so on.

Comment: So I'm gonna mark this as the answer since the "issue" was inadvertently solved despite a lack of consensus from the community.

Comment: `[change-directory]`, anyone? Or maybe `[cd-command]`?

Comment: The "command" one makes sense, the other, not so much. @dan